# Suggest carbon accounting software to capture GHG emissions from vehicles

Tags: accounting

I'm looking for a carbon accounting tool, which can help in calculating scope 1, scope 2 and scope 3 GHG emission of a supply chain and vehicle.

Comment: To get a wider response you need to explain the terms.